# Sequence of actions for screeps

Tags: screeps

I've looked the web for info about what can I do in the current turn with my creep, and I found conflicting statements.

http://screeps.wikia.com/wiki/Creep -- from comments here, we can build and move at the same turn, or move then transfer energy

http://www.reddit.com/r/screeps/comments/2pqhsz/gaps_in_the_documentation/ -- and this source states that I can do only one action with animation, that is, I can't move and build at the same turn. And as far as I get it, it states that I need to do animation action first, then any of other actions.

Which is right?

**Questions I raise here:**

- Given I'm 4 tiles far from enemy, can I move in and shoot at the same
  turn?
- Given I'm 3 tiles far from enemy, can I shoot and move out at the same turn?
- Given questions above, which creep moves first, mine, or enemy? Can I have a situation, when creep shot and move out of my range before I can shoot back? Or all actions are performed at the same time?
- Can any action happen between robot move and rangeAttack?
- I have 5 creeps with CARRY in a line. Can I transferEnergy from first to second, from second to third, ..., from four to five in a same turn?
- What happens when I order to transferEnergy twice in a turn? Which one of this two invocations work?
- Can I move and attack/build at the same turn?
- Can I rangeAttack and attack at the same turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, these questions are about gameplay, not coding, so you better ask it on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screeps) (another StackExchange project) rather than StackOverflow.

> Given I'm 4 tiles far from enemy, can I move in and shoot at the same turn?

No.

> Given I'm 3 tiles far from enemy, can I shoot and move out at the same turn?

Yes.

> Given questions above, which creep moves first, mine, or enemy?

They move both simultaneously.

> Can I have a situation, when creep shot and move out of my range before I can shoot back?

No. If you get such situation - that's a bug, report it.

> Or all actions are performed at the same time?

Exactly.

> Can any action happen between robot move and rangeAttack?

Moving is performed after all other actions during dedicated movement game step.

> I have 5 creeps with CARRY in a line. Can I transferEnergy from first to second, from second to third, ..., from four to five in a same turn?

No, you have to do it in 5 turns.

> What happens when I order to transferEnergy twice in a turn? Which one of this two invocations work?

The last one. The same with all other actions.

> Can I move and attack/build at the same turn?

Yes.

> Can I rangeAttack and attack at the same turn?

Yes. But you can't heal and rangedHeal at the same time though.

Comment: I realized that after I already posted a question. Thanks for link on Arqade, it seems related question is already asked there http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/200912/are-any-actions-of-screeps-mutually-exclusive-to-eachother